# Multiple Json Objects Imported into SQL Server Table

Tags: json, sql-server

I am trying to Import the Currency Data into a table.

I am able to import one of the data objects by specifying `FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$.currency."0"')` however I am struggling to find a solution which helps me gather all 5 currencies into there own column.

I want to use the unique JSON Object headers for each currency as a data Item (DefaultCurrencyCode)

This is the JSON Data:

```
"currency": {
    "0": {
      "ISOCode": "USD",
      "name": "US Dollar",
      "symbol": "$",
    },
    "1": {
      "ISOCode": "IEP",
      "name": "Irish Pound or Punt",
      "symbol": "£",
    },
    "2": {
      "ISOCode": "BEF",
      "name": "Belgian Franc",
      "symbol": "₣",
    },
    "3": {
      "ISOCode": "ZAR",
      "name": "South African Rand",
      "symbol": "R",
    },
    "4": {
      "ISOCode": "JPY",
      "name": "Japanese Yen",
      "symbol": "¥",
    }
   }
```

This is my SQL Server code:

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK 'C:\dev\src\Client\config\common\config.json', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS j

SELECT ISOCode, name, symbol ,DefaultCurrencyCode
INTO TestTable2
  FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$.currency."0"')
  WITH (
    ISOCode VARCHAR(10),
    name VARCHAR(50),
    symbol VARCHAR(50),
    DefaultCurrencyCode INT)

    Select * From TestTable2
```

This is my current output, however I am trying to get all of them.
[image]

Comment: See if this helps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 It looks like you need to remove the `, '$.currency."0"'` in the open and format the columns in the `WITH` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional `OPENJSON` call with explicit schema to get data from nested `JSON` objects.

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
   "currency": {
    "0": {
      "ISOCode": "USD",
      "name": "US Dollar",
      "symbol": "$"
    },
    "1": {
      "ISOCode": "IEP",
      "name": "Irish Pound or Punt",
      "symbol": "£"
    },
    "2": {
      "ISOCode": "BEF",
      "name": "Belgian Franc",
      "symbol": "₣"
    },
    "3": {
      "ISOCode": "ZAR",
      "name": "South African Rand",
      "symbol": "R"
    },
    "4": {
      "ISOCode": "JPY",
      "name": "Japanese Yen",
      "symbol": "¥"
    }
   }
}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j2.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.currency') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
    ISOCode NVARCHAR(10),
    name NVARCHAR(50),
    symbol NVARCHAR(50),
    DefaultCurrencyCode INT
) j2
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
ISOCode name                symbol  DefaultCurrencyCode
-------------------------------------------------------
USD     US Dollar           $   
IEP     Irish Pound or Punt £   
BEF     Belgian Franc       ₣   
ZAR     South African Rand  R   
JPY     Japanese Yen        ¥
```